# Is using Class.getMethods() a heavy operation in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a question about the performance of the java "Class" API. I have a requirement where I have database values which could go like `/car` or `/cars[0]/make`. For each of those database values I have to see whether the particular class I am dealing with, has a setter method for `/car` like `setCar` ( or for `/cars[0]/make` a `setCars` method). Currently, I just iteratre through all the declared methods of the class (using `getMethods`) and then do some string checking to see using the method names match the database value. I do not invoke any method, when I do this. Although, this is using the `Method` API, it is really not doing any method invokation. Is this still a heavy operation in terms of java reflection? To paraphrase this, is this java reflection in use?

Comment: This has code smell in my opinion. I would look to your code design.

Comment: If you're doing this, I would look at caching method names.

Comment: @tjg184 There is a reflection caching utility class we use, which caches the method names, however I'd have to extract the possible method name from the database value i.e in case of the value /cars[0]/make, I'd have to extract "cars" from this (using String maniuplation) and pass it to the API, which would look for method names corresponding to "cars" like "getCars"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are using reflection by the call getMethods.  If you are concerned about performance you could profile your code using a java profiler like [JIP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiprof/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, java reflection is used to look up the declared method and the lookup is already an expensive operation without invoking the method afterwards.

However the OpenJDK (the default implementation of java) uses an internal cache, so subsequent lookups for declared methods on the same class are way faster.

Any major framework for Object mapping (to database or JSON) uses reflection, so as long as your application does not deal with high frequency trading in sub-millisecond reaction time, you should be fine with using reflection here.